# md-sidenav overflow not working

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

This is a Firefox issue, Chrome works fine.

Sidenav its not "overflowing" the content

To see in action, just visit the link below using Firefox, to get it right, use Chrome.

[Angular Material Demo  v0.9.8](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdJRez)

There is no much to say.

Any tips?

```
<div layout="row" flex>
   <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      ....
      ....  // overflow content
   </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

What i notice its a overflow blinks when page load.

Comment: what is the material version you are using?

Comment: The codepen seems to have errors in its HTML. For instance, there are two `<html>` start tags. And since different browsers respond differently to errors, well, it's no surprise you get different results.

Comment: @MrLister the demo i took from angular material himself, i could not find html errors , anyway, did you tried to fix and see if works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easily fixed by changing line 16 to the following:

```
<div layout="row" flex style="overflow:hidden">
```

This shouldn't be necessary, and I am going to look into adding a fix for this right now.  In the meantime, the solution above should work.